# How can select specific text value from <select> <option...?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value from select option selected text (not option value) in HTML and javascript?

Once I able to get the value, I wanted to get the specific string just like the one below.

Value is 2.500 and text Option value is 250 bonus.  I wanted to get the 250 and assign its own input hidden value.

Thanks

Comment: "Just like the one below"? Which one. We don't see anything

Answer (score 2):

Okay, from what you have given, I can guess that you need to get the option's text.

```
function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Use this way:

```
var text = getSelectedText('selectID');
```

---

Or as [Derek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283863/derek) suggested, you can have it in one line too:

```
var text = elementId.querySelector("option:checked").innerText
```

**Note:** This works only in modern browsers.

Comment: [One line](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uj6Jw): `elementId.querySelector("option:checked").innerText`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks. Updated the answer with yours too! BTW, `querySelector` works only with modern browsers right?

Comment: It works with >IE7. [reference](http://caniuse.com/queryselector)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar - It works in IE8 and above... and I don't really consider IE8 as a "modern" browser though. ;)

Comment: Okay, didn't know that `querySelector` works in IE 8! :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#">
<input type="hidden" name="bonus_hidden" value="" />
<select name="b" onchange="document.forms[0].elements['bonus_hidden'].value=document.forms[0].elements['b'].options[document.forms[0].elements['b'].selectedIndex].text">
<option value="1.000">100 bonus</option>
<option value="1.500">150 bonus</option>
<option value="2.000">200 bonus</option>
<option value="2.500">250 bonus</option>
</select>
</form>
```